# How to check if vungle video is complete or user close the vungle video?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am working on vungle video integration in cocos 2d and and running the ad successfully.
In app i want to provide some points for watching video.. which i can set up.. but the problem is how to check whether the user has watched the video or close it ..

https://v.vungle.com/dev/ios

I am using the above help.. but not able to make it work..Please help me in checking whether app is ads are close or watched completely

Comment: Not enough information and your link doesn't work (requires a login). Have you checked their documentation?

Comment: i want to provide 50 points once the user watch the video..
but the score is update if i go to next video not on the same screen..So i would like to reload the screen or refresh to make score update. For that i need to check whether complete video is played or user close the ads. So i can push the view again so score is update.

yes,i have check their documentation and the link in my question leads to that

Comment: Again, the link requires a login and from the looks of the URL it's pointing to a general "iOS dev" page of theirs. Since the vungle API isn't publicly available it's better to take this to their support forum or contact.

Comment: Okay.. i have send a message to them and hope i get reply soon.
And thanks for your help and suggestion on the issue...!!

Comment: you can check by comparing total video duration - movieViewed duration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)vungleSDKwillCloseAdWithViewInfo:(NSDictionary *)viewInfo willPresentProductSheet:(BOOL)willPresentProductSheet {
//Verify that the view was completed before rewarding the user
BOOL completedView = [[viewInfo valueForKey:@"completedView"] boolValue];
if (completedView) {
    //View was successfully completed, do your stuff...
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Few months back I did use vungle. Check below code, that worked for me

```
-(void)vungleMoviePlayed:(VGPlayData*)playData
{
    if(playData.movieTotal == playData.movieViewed)
    {
        printf("Video fully watched\n");
        mSeenVungleVideo = true;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Player aborted video at middle\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,can you help me with what value you pass to call this method ?
it would really help

Comment: its a delegate method fired when user close vungle

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have changed since NatureFriend's answer. It's now:

```
- (void)vungleSDKwillCloseAdWithViewInfo:(NSDictionary*)viewInfo willPresentProductSheet:(BOOL)willPresentProductSheet;
{
    // video done here.
}
```

It's possible at this point it will show a "Product Sheet". If you want to know when that closes, you can implement this delegate:

```
- (void)vungleSDKwillCloseProductSheet:(id)productSheet
{
    // product sheet closed here
}
```